# "//" button on hp server case

Tags: hp, hardware

I was wondering what the button with the symbol "//" does? I couldnt find much from a google search. It is a HP server case, product number SCS299UP.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/10wsk0o/8]

Comment: At least post the model of the server.

Comment: Are you sure that's an HP server? It doesn't look like any I've seen, the color and styling are off, and the LEDs looks like they only light up green. Also, the product number doesn't match anything.

Comment: actually you are right, there is no hp marking on the server case itself. The tape drive is only hp. There is no other marking on the case itself.

Comment: You could open up the case to trace the wire...or just press the button.

Comment: To me this looks like an Intel case or a case housing an Intel server board

Comment: This is a bit weak. Sorry...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Well, you got the manufacturer of the server wrong, evidently don't know what a reset button is, or the fact that they're ubiquitous on server hardware (and even desktops, for that matter), didn't know or check the ISO standard symbol, didn't check the manual... maybe other things too.  All that... that's weak.

Comment: When in doubt press it. At worst, you've just reset a mission critical server. That said, that's probably very obviously where a reset switch has been for every system I have used that didn't have a fancy gaming system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to hazard it's the reset button.
[ISO 7000:2012 - 1027](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#!iso:grs:7000:4:1027) states the following of the symbol.

> To identify the control that returns the machine mode to a previously determined operating condition or resets the content of an electronic file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Or perhaps the button is just a shortcut for commenting code lines. :-)